# How to access spartacus cdc gigya data?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, gigya, hybris-data-hub

I am using Spartacus 4.3.

I apologize if this is a stupid question as I'm still quite new to Spartacus and SAP.

I've set up gigya SAP Customer Data Cloud Integration as described here https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/cdc-integration/.

The service is using accounts.getAccountInfo REST as I can see the request being made in my Network tab.

I need to access the **data** object from the request response, which I cannot find in any Spartacus service.

My problem is that I cannot find where the request is being made from, and I cannot access the **data** object.

I've tried creating an adapter to make another request, but I am getting a 403 error. I don't think this would be a good solution anyways.

I've also tried using the gigya object on the window to call `window.gigya.accounts.getAccountInfo()`. This function makes a request to the endpoint, but does not return it's response. I also don't think it's a great solution either, since it makes a new request.

Any help would be really appreciated as I've been really stuck with this one...